# Disable button using session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, jqgrid

i have a jqgrid and button image column which look like this one:

button | sample1 | red 
button | sample2 | blue 
button | sample3 | red 
button | sample4 | red 
button | sample5 | blue 
button | sample6 | green

what need to do is this:

if the user has a session id of red Session["Color"] = red;

then all button that is not red will be disabled.
same with the other color.

but if session color is not there. it will just hide the column

here is my sample code:

```
var sessionColor = '<%=Session["Color"]%>';
    if (sessionColor == 'red') { 
                    // code here
                    // hide button green and blue
                   }
                   if (sessionColor == 'green') {
                       // code here
                       // hide button red and blue
                   }
                   if (sessionColor == 'blue') {
                       // code here
                       // hide button gren and blue
                   }
                   else { //hide all button}
```

problem: how will i disable the button if the user with "red" session will log in.

Comment: i dont know how will i disable/hide the button. if it contains "red"

Comment: Use button Collection method, and button.Visible = true; and button.Visible = false; indeed the code/

Comment: Useful Question I added +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

Try the Button Collection Ideas. See the Below Code.

```
var sessionColor = Session["Color"].ToString();
                if (sessionColor == "red")
                {
                    var buttons = ButtonPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>();
                    foreach (var button in buttons)
                    {
                        if (button.BackColor == Color.Red)
                        {
                            button.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
                else if (sessionColor == "green")
                {
                    var buttons = ButtonPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>();
                    foreach (var button in buttons)
                    {
                        if (button.BackColor == Color.Green)
                        {
                            button.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (sessionColor == "blue")
                {
                    var buttons = ButtonPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>();
                    foreach (var button in buttons)
                    {
                        if (button.BackColor == Color.Blue)
                        {
                            button.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            button.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var buttons = ButtonPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>();
                    foreach (var button in buttons)
                    {
                        button.Visible = false;

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Better to use switch instead of if and elses

Comment: @NagaHarishMovva Is it need here. Code has only three if statement! If I change to Switch will code Speed Performance?

Comment: I agree if it is only two to three it say ok. I did not said don't use if. I said it is "better to use switch". +1

Comment: @NagaHarishMovva Oh its ok friend.,.